Behave python - driver options auto correct is suggesting only in function where driver is initialized. In other functions auto correct is not working
Behave python - driver options auto correct is suggesting only in function where driver is initialized. In other functions auto correct is not working.
However, when I type the code manually and run it. Execution happens without any issue.
Pre-requisite:

Installed behave and Selenium
Using chrome driver for automation. Chrome is already installed in the machine

Problem statement:
For example in def before_scenario() - driver methods are suggesting as expected.
enter image description here
But in the next function def after_scenario() - driver methods are not suggesting.
enter image description here
However, while typing manually and execute the code, it works fine [no error]. But I really want to resolve this auto correct option in my code
Appreciate your support!!
I'm trying to use the auto correct driver function in all the files where ever I'm calling driver.
Example:
IDE: Pycharm
Language: Python
Framework: behave
def before_scenario(context, driver):
    browser = configReader.read_configuration("basic info","browser")
    if browser.__eq__("chrome"):
        context.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    context.driver.get(configReader.read_configuration("basic info","url"))
    context.driver.maximize_window() 
""=====> at this def method I get all the driver auto correct methods like maximize_window(), find_element() etc.."""

def after_scenario(context, driver):
    context.driver.quit() 
"""====> but, in this def method I cannot get any driver methods. .quit() is written manually here""

Highlighting point here is, code works without any error. But in this framework I want the driver methods should suggest in all the def methods


It seems to me that this is an issue with the IDE. You should probably add a tag for it and maybe someone can help.
